# Date exception in German windows during insert MS access vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have written an insert query which inserts datetime along with other columns. It works fine for all locations except when
my German client logs in and runs the application it gives him below error. I have formatted the datevalue to yyyy-mm-dd to make 
culture independent.
MS access database is stored in a server in US.
German client is running application from Germany.

```
strDateSubmit = dtpDateSub.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

strSaveOSTR = "INSERT INTO " & strOSTR & " ([OSTR #],[OSTR Type],[# of Samples],[RA#],[Customer],[SKF #],[Test Description]," & _
        "[TestLength],[TestUnit],[TestLengthDays],[Requestor],[Date Submitted],[Seals Avail],[Fixtures Available],[Peripherals Avail],[PO Avail]," & _
        "[Machine Type],[Hours to Process],[Location],[Current Status],[ErrorsPresent],[ContaminType]" & SampleREcvd1 & ", [Emp_ID],[Industry])" & _
        " Values ( '" & strOSTRNum & "', '" & cmbOSTRTypes.Text & "', " & intSamples & ", '" & strRA & "', '" & strCustomer & "', '" & strSKFNum & _
        "', '" & strTestDescr & "', " & intTestLength & ", '" & strTestUnits & "', '" & txtTestLDays.Text & "', '" & strRequestor & "', #" & strDateSubmit & "#, '" & strSealAvail & _
        "', '" & strFixtAvail & "', '" & strPheriAvail & "', '" & strPOAvail & "', '" & strMachineClass & "', " & intHrstoProc & ",'" & g_objProp.Location & _
        "', '" & strStatus & "', '" & ErrorsPresent & "', '" & ContaminationType & "'" & SampleREcvd2 & ", '" & emp_id & "', '" & Industry & "')"
```

> Error: Syntaxfehler in Datum in Abfrageausdruck '#01.02.2016'

Comment: Do you have control over the Access DB? If so why don´t you use the Date data type? A date is a type and should not be stored with a format.

Comment: Yes. I have control over access db. Do you mean to say use datevalue in the insert query instead of a formatted string?

Comment: Not only in the insert query. You would have to adopt the column data type in the access table. This is a more convenient way to store dates.

Comment: Nothing indicates that `[Date Submitted]` should not be of data type Date.

Comment: [Date Submitted] is indeed a Date/Time column in the access database

Comment: Then again why `ToString(yyyy-MM-dd)` and no parametrized query with a date parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need a more strict format of the date expression string:

```
strDateSubmit = dtpDateSub.Value.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd")
```

This will always return a date like `"2016/02/01"` (no dots or dashes), and it will concatenate correctly here:

```
"', #" & strDateSubmit & "#, '"
```

as you intend.

Comment: Thank you. I realised that its the "." dots in the date which are causing these exceptions. I did as you suggested above and it works.

Comment: Just wondering, so .NET programmers working from Germany have to convert all their dates to some format without dots, otherwise oledb driver wouldn't allow their natural dates with dots to get executed at all!

Comment: @Sameer no, they wouldn't, because they would use parameterized queries.

Comment: The root of the issue is that _Access SQL_ expects a date/time value either as a _value_ or as a _properly formatted string expression_ following either the weird US format or the more straight ISO sequence with a date delimiter of either "/" or "-", thus (outside a US environment) you have to force the separator by escaping it to make sure it won't be replaced by a localized separator.

Answer (score 3):

Do yourself a favor: Scrap the dynamic SQL and use a parameterized query, e.g.,

```
sampleSQL = "INSERT INTO TableName ([Date Submitted]) VALUES (?)"
Dim cmd = New OleDbCommand(sampleSQL, conn)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", dtpDateSub.Value)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

That way you can use the actual DateTime value returned by the DateTimePicker. You don't have to be concerned with locale settings or string formats or any of those aggravations.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I agree that parametrized queries are the best way to go. But for me its probably too late since delivery is handful of days away.