# Decimal number throwing exception during INSERT

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have written an INSERT statement from inside a VB.NET application which inserts a bunch of data into a table which includes a Number column. MS access is the database. "Cycles" is the column in the table defined as of type "Number". I insert decimal values with two digits after decimal point for insertion into this column. The insert works all fine except from Germany. I realise that in Germany, they use "," (comma) instead of a "." (dot) for decimal point separation. Hence this application when run from a German windows machine fails at insert. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formatting of numbers is a presentation concern, not a data persistence concern. If number-to-string formatting is affecting your SQL commands then it sounds like you're doing string concatenation to form a SQL command in a string. **Do not do this**.

Instead, use a parameterized query, that way the raw binary value of the number is sent to the database instead of a formatted string, like so:

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Foo ( DecimalValue ) VALUES ( @value )")
cmd.Parameters.Add( "@value", SqlDbType.Decimal ).Value = someDecimal
```

Note the syntax for parameter placeholders depends on which database software you're using. Consult your system's SQL reference for specifics.

Note that if you want to ensure that a decimal number is formatted the same regardless of computer language settings do this:

```
Dim s As String
Dim d As Decimal = 2.0
s = d.ToString( CultureInfo.InvariantCulture )
```

I wish .NET had a built-in `ToStringInvariant` method to avoid needing to import `System.Globalization`.

Answer (score 2):

Just as with [my answer to your other question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35157612/2144390), your problem will go away if you use a parameterized query. Your comment to that answer claims that it is too late to change your code, but perhaps now you will reconsider. You can either keep throwing kluges into your code to "fix" the problems faced by your German users, or you can alter your code to do things properly.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree now!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
'n as integer
'MyArr() as double

For i=1 to n
   MyArr(i,1)=Replace(MyArr(i, 1), ",", ".")
next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Access Decimal value definition:

[image: .Parameters.AddWithValue("@decFRRate", ldecFRRate)]